# How to force a swapped-out zsh process to swap in?

Tags: linux, zsh

I usually have many long-running zsh processes (in spread out over various screen sessions) on my computer, but shells that haven't been used for a while tend to be swapped out. When I switch to such a swapped-out shell and press enter (at an empty prompt) it takes many seconds before the shell responds and a new prompt is displayed (but after that it resumes working perfectly).

To lessen my annoyance I'd like to have a command (e.g. `unswap PID`) that I can invoke (from another, already responding shell) to force a shell swap in.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

**P.S.** I started off by looking around for a command to ask the system to swap in *any* process – but I have found no such thing, making me believe that this is not possible. I've here focused my question to `zsh`, since this is the case that really interests me, and I'm hoping there might be a solution for that particular case. If you have a more general method that would work for any process (and not just zsh) that would be quite welcome too.

**P.P.S.** At first I thought of using a trap function inside my shell, which then did some activity (anything) enough to cause the shell to swap in. Having tried this with the `WINCH` signal however, I've found that it doesn't work. (Maybe the signal is not delivered to a swapped out process? Are any signals?)

---

**EDIT:** In my typical case I have a bunch of `zsh` processes running, and then I've left my browser open (with multiple Gmail, Facebook etc tabs) for a bit too long, causing the browser to hoard all of the available RAM and *squeezing* everything else out into swap. The desktop goes unresponsive for a while, but that clears up kinda quickly. However, when reattaching to a screen session each shell have to be waken up manually (going through them and pressing enter in each shell).

Comment: swapped processes do get signals. Maybe you could `swapoff` and `swapon` .... assuming there is enough RAM to do that.

Comment: “Swap in” is a difficult concept: if you swap in all the files and libraries that the process maps, that could include a lot of data that it isn't going to use. See [how to “unswap” my desktop](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6267/how-to-unswap-my-desktop) on [unix.se] (same question except not specifically about zsh).

Comment: @Gilles Thanx for pointing to that question, that was precisely what I needed to find the answer.

Comment: Hmm. This question probably belong on the [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange site, rather than here. – Can questions be moved between sites?

Comment: @ZrajmCAkfohg If you're approaching this as a user then it belongs on [unix.se]. If you want to program this feature into zsh, then it belongs on [so]. It's borderline. Matt provided an SO answer, yours is a U&L answer. If you want this question migrated, you can flag for it — but it would be a duplicate of the question I linked to, so there isn't a lot of use for migrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/73438) one can use `gdb` to dump the memory of a process in order to get it unswapped.

I also found out [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68434) that there is a `gcore` script to do this directly from the command line (instead of first having to start `gdb` and then execute additional commands inside of it), so invoking:

```
gcore -o /tmp/SOMETHING PID1 PID2 PID3
```

will cause programs with PID1, PID2 and PID3 to become unswapped, and dump their contents to files `/tmp/SOMETHING.PID1`, `/tmp/SOMETHING.PID2` etc.

There is also a Python script in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6271) which does the same thing. Though, admittedly – as a response to this question – in a much nicer fashion, since this scripts output the dump on `STDOUT` which we can pipe straight to hell (uhm, I mean `/dev/null`, of course) since we're only interested in the side effect of unswapping anyway.

Comment: Since `gcore` is a shell script, you can edit the script not to save the dump output in a file, but into `/dev/null` instead.   There is a limit on comment size, so I can't post that script here; see my separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since `gcore` is a shell script, you can edit the script not to save the dump output in a file, but into `/dev/null` instead, e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh -u

# Use </dev/null to avoid touching interactive terminal if it is
# available but not accessible as GDB would get stopped on SIGTTIN.
#
exec </dev/null

for pid do
        gdb --nx --batch --readnever \
            -ex "set pagination off" -ex "set height 0" -ex "set width 0" \
            -ex "attach $pid" -ex "gcore /dev/null" -ex detach -ex quit
done
```

The above does give an error `Memory read failed for corefile section`, but it works well enough to pull most/all of the process into memory and out of swap.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried/can you decrease the kernel [swappiness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swappiness) value so zsh is less likely to be swapped out?

If you're willing to recompile zsh, you could insert a call to [mlockall](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mlockall)( MCL_CURRENT | MCL_FUTURE ) in main(). This prevents it from being swapped out in the first place.

Or add a signal handler that calls [mlockall](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mlockall)( MCL_CURRENT ) followed by [munlockall](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mlockall)().

Comment: Well, I don't want to force `zsh` to *never* swap out, I just want to be able to swap it in again on command. (With sometimes 50+ shells running on my machine for months on end, I think it better not to force all of them to stay in my precious RAM.) – Likewise with changing the `swappiness` value. I don't want change to much in my system, I just want the option of manually waking my processes up from their swappy slumber.

Comment: "you can see that you cannot use the Linux swappiness value to influence swap’s behavior with respect to RAM usage. It just doesn’t work like that."  https://www.howtogeek.com/449691/what-is-swapiness-on-linux-and-how-to-change-it/